# Proxy (transparent) that retries on 503 errors

Tags: proxy, http, cache, 503-error

In a devops setting, a docker container needs to have its https traffic filtered through a retrying proxy/cache, as the requests sometimes fail due to 503 errors. It seems like squid can do this, but the config line

```
retry_on_error on
```

did not avoid the 503 failures. Another possibility would be to use [the envoy proxy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/), but it seems to be a bit hard to configure.

Would envoy be a way to transparently proxy with [retrying on 5xx errors](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/faq/transient_failures.html?highlight=retry)? Does squid need additional configuration? Is there another (easier) way to transparently proxy and cache HTTPS traffic with retrying on 503 errors?

Comment: I just feel like adding that so far the answer I keep receiving for this question is that I should fix my backend in order to avoid 5xx errors completely. The problem is that in some cases, like mine, the backend is not under your control, and all you can do is work it around :-(